# High/highly, which one is most appropriate in the given sentence.

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

He thinks high/highly of me. 
Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the adverbial form of "high" is "high": so you can say "The ball curved high above the crowd".

However, there are two instances where "highly" is used:

One is as an intensifier: "That food is highly spiced".

The other is the idiom "think highly of". "To think high of" is simply not English.

Answer (score 1):

/He thinks highly of me/ is the correct one. One can't "think high of someone" in English.
Alternatives: He holds me in high esteem. He holds me in high regard (a bit old fashioned).

It's an idiom: to think highly of someone. (And no, one cannot "think lowly of someone".)  There is also to "think kindly of someone". It may be argued that highly is an adverb describing think but that is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

SUPPLEMENTAL to the answers of Lambie and Colin Fine

The *why* part of your question cannot be addressed as a matter of formal syntax; you can only take *think ADV of NOUN* as an idiomatic construction, not susceptible of further analysis.

The verb *think* has a very complicated history. It actually represents the collapse of two related but semantically and syntactically quite distinct Old English verbs into a single form in Middle English, so it already had very muddled types of argumentation 800 years ago; and as its semantic sense expanded the muddle got even worse.

The modern idiom *think ADV of NOUN* seems to have arisen fairly abruptly at the end of the 16th century. My guess is that what's involved is a conflation of genuinely adverbial constructions like *I think contemptuously of him* with nominal constructions like *I think nothing of him*, *I think ill of him*, mediated by the nominal but ambiguous *I think well of him*.

But that's no more than a guess. Wherever the construction came from, people liked it and adopted it; and since language is nothing if not democratic, that's what we say today.